# What's the difference between halt and shutdown now?

Tags: halt

`halt` can turn off the machine,

but `shutdown now` doesn't turn off ,it just logs the `root` off.

Anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a modern Linux systems halt calls [shutdown](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) with a suitable argument -h ([halt](http://linux.die.net/man/8/halt)) or -r ([reboot](http://linux.die.net/man/8/reboot)) these are the equivalent of [runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) 0 and 6. Running `shutdown now` puts the system into runlevel 1 (single user mode). If you want to halt the system with shutdown use `shutdown -h now`.

On Solaris 10/11 [halt](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/6mbb1kq2m/index.html) is quite brutal, it just flushes the disk caches and powers off the system - no attempt is made to run any scripts or shutdown smf facilities.

Other systems may do things differently too.

Answer (score 2):

I assume Linux? (Good practice to tell or at least tag the OS).

'shutdown now' puts the system in init 1, while 'shutdown -h now' halts it 'now'.

From the manual of shutdown

> shutdown does its job by signalling the init process, asking it to change the runlevel.  Runlevel 0 is used to halt the system, runlevel  6  is  used  to
>          reboot  the  system,  and runlevel 1 is used to put to system into a state where administrative tasks can be performed; this is the default if neither the -h or -r flag is given to shutdown.  To see which actions are taken on halt or reboot see the appropriate entries for these runlevels in the file
>          /etc/inittab.

Answer (score 0):

thats a "long time ago" commands. 
shutdown or poweroff -- turnoff computer 
halt -- prepares computer to be shutted down after user push the power button.